# MongoDB driver not working with Apache on MAMP (Windows)

Tags: mamp

I've spent the last few hours trying to get the Mongo driver to play nicely with MAMP. At first, I thought the issue was PHP; I installed the thread-safe version the matches the architecture MAMP is built against (x86) and the required version of PHP (7.0.9), but still couldn't see it in `phpinfo()`. Of course, scripts on the web server couldn't find the `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` class, so they wouldn't work.

So I wrote a small script and ran it through CLI, and it worked! I'm able to connect to a local Mongo instance with no trouble. This means that PHP is able to load the extension, which in turn means that something else must be the cause.

I'm going to say that Apache is the culprit. I read another post where someone said they tried older versions of Apache and PHP until it worked, but I'd like to try and make it work with my current version of PHP. Is there something I'm missing that would make the Mongo driver not work when using Apache?

I'm using MAMP 3.2.2, which is the latest version for Windows clients.

Answer (score 0):

After about a day of tinkering, I gave up and used XAMMP - it worked just fine.